# Multiply all elements in array

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find an example here what I'm really looking for.
I'd like to multiply all array elements, so if an array contains [1,2,3] the sum would be 1*2*3=6;
So far I've got this code, but it returns undefined.

```
function multiply (array) {
    var sum=1;
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum * array[i];
    } 
    return sum;
}
console.log(multiply[1,2,3]);
```

Could anyone please explain, what am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't your last line be like this console.log(multiply([1,2,3]));

Answer (score 70):

The cause is already known. Here's an alternative - using `Array.reduce` for your method:

```js
console.log( [1, 2, 3].reduce( (a, b) => a * b ) );
console.log( Array.from( {length: 20} )
  .map( (v, i) => i + 1 )
  .reduce( (a,b) => a * b, 1 )
  .toLocaleString());

// for empty arrays, use some initial value
const arr = [];
if (arr.reduce( (a, b) => a * b, -1 ) === -1) {
  console.error(`The given array ${arr} is empty`);
}
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Don't forget to check your desired browser support for Array.reduce : http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.reduce otherwise, lodash/underscore's _.reduce is a nice alternative

Comment: It is mentioned and there's a polyfill in the MDN-link (the 'See also' link in the answer)

Comment: ES6: `[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a * b);`

Comment: has issues if the array is empty

Comment: I wanted a plain solution like with algorithms and more code so that I can understand the process not directly going with the ``reduce`` function

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi The link in the answer gives ample information on the workings of `Array.reduce`. I'd suggest you study that page

Comment: Is there any way to check in reduce fucntion if an element value is zero break at the reduce and the product is zero.

Comment: @KiranKumar You can't break from a reduce lambda. You _can_ do `[1, 2, 0, 3].reduce( (a, b) => b > 0 ?  a * b : 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 18):

The alternative way to use `Array.reduce` should have the initial value set to 1 or else our function will return 0 no matter what.

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b)=> a*b, 1)
```

per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: If no initial value is provided, the first value in the array will act as the initial value, so this also works fine: `[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b)=> a*b)`

Answer (score 9):

You need to have `()` when you call the function.

Like `multiply([1,2,3])`

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkf43/)**

Comment: @JohSmith, glad I could help. Always good to have many people looking at the code :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling multiply as a function:

```
multiply([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reduce() method executes a provided function for each value of the array and reduces the array to a single value

```js
    const arr = [1,2,3];
    const sum = arr.reduce((prevValue,curValue) => {
        return prevValue * curValue
    },1);
    console.log(sum);
```

**prevValue** is the initial value and it's equal **1** in this example

**curValue** is the value of the current element in array

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to do any arithmetic operation on array

```js
myMathArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
let myValue = myMathArray.reduce((a,b)=> a*b)
console.log(myValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply some consecutive numbers like 1,2,3 then, then apply this code and enter the number in the console (arr)

```
let array = [];

function factorisation(arr) {
    for (let j = arr; j > 0; j--) {
        array.push(j);
    }
    return multiply();
}

function multiply() {
    var sum = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum * array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(factorisation(5));
//5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#multiply) >=4.7:

```
_.reduce(array, _.multiply)
```

or, using all three arguments:

```
_.reduce(array, _.multiply, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use recursion

```js
const productOfArray = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return arr[0] * productOfArray(arr.slice(1));
}

console.log(productOfArray([1,2,3,10])); // 60
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified using recursion...

```
    function productOfArray(arr) {

    let sum = 1;
    
    function sumHelper(nums) {

        if(nums.length === 0)
        return 0;

        sum = sum * nums[nums.length-1];
        nums.length--;
        
        sumHelper(nums);
        
    }

    sumHelper(arr);
    
    return sum;
    
}

console.log(productOfArray([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Multiply all array elements:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,2];
use reduce();
const multiply = arr.reduce((preValue,nextValue)=>preValue*nextValue);
console.log(multiply); //12
```

Comment: Use correct formating to write question