# Multiply each values in array with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating

I have a array in javascript like that:

```
var odds = [1.80, 2.90, 3.1, 1.05];
```

I want to multiply all float values in array, like (1.80 * 2.90 * 3.1 * 1.05)

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175063/multiply-all-elements-in-array

Comment: learn some basics about loops and come back with what you tried

Comment: Marked as duplicate when the solution from the duplicate url only responds to half of the question, he asked to multiply only the float numbers not all the numbers on array. Maye re-check the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this task.

`reduce` offers a return value, which is for this problem an inportant feature.

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), for example,  requires a variable for keeping the intermediate result.

```js
var odds = [1.80, 2.90, 3.1, 1.05];
document.body.textContent = odds.reduce(function (a, b) { return a * b; });
```

Comment: Any reason of using `reduce` over `forEach` ? Small description would ve helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `for` loop for the following as:

```
var res = 1;
for(var i=0;i<odds.length;i++)
   { 
     res*=odds[i];
 }
```

The result is in `res`

**Explanation:**: We will iterate over the array and keep on multiplying each element in it with a element having the previously stored result(in this case `res` and initially is is 1) and finally the result is stored in `res`