# Multiply each element from array by every element

Tags: arrays, for-loop

JavaScript

I need to do this with for loop,
I want to multiply each element from array (2 * 5 * 10 * 12)

Example

```
var arrNum = [2,5,10,12]

var sum = 0

for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {

sum = arrNum[i] * // I don't know what to do
```

Any ideas :) ?

I did something like this

```
var arrNum = [2,5,10,12]

var sum = 0
var temp = 1

for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++){
temp *=arrNumbers[i]
if(i== arrNumbers.length-1){
sum = temp 
}
}
```

Comment: Multiply `sum` (or should it be called "multiplication"?) by each element on every iteration (and remember to close that `for` loop)

Comment: Declare a `product` variable with the value of 1 and inside your loop multiply each number of the array to product and assign it back to the product.

Comment: What @GalAbra said, but make sure you initialize `sum=1`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Good call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply all elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175063/multiply-all-elements-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [2,5,10,12].reduce(function(a,b){return a*b;});
```

I think your question needs more explaining, I suppose you're in JS environment.

Notice the advanced funtions of ES6; I suggest to get in deep of all these advanced operations.

Please notice that under the hood the operation will be exact a for-loop, but the reduce hides the complexity and leave everything cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var total = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    total *= arrNum[i];
}
```

Comment: Why would you keep two separate variables?

Comment: @GalAbra You're right, sorry. I just woke up. Edited.

Comment: Good morning, then! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will always get result as 0 because

your starting sum condition is 0 then multiplying it by any number in the array will always give you 0.

Here is what you should do -

```
var sum = 1

for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {

    sum = arrNum[i] * sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the first element of the array in sum
then multiply sum * array of i which start at 1 since we put first element in sum and then put the result back in the sum

```js
var arrNum = [2,5,10,12]

var sum = arrNum[0]

for(var i = 1; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
  sum = sum * arrNum[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I did something like this

var arrNum = [2,5,10,12]

var sum = 0
var temp = 1

for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++){
temp *=arrNumbers[i]
if(i== arrNumbers.length-1){
sum = temp 
}
}
```

it works, but var sum is not a real 0 ...