# How to multiply all arguments together inside an array and return the product

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to multiply all arguments together inside an array and return the product

- if no arguments are passed in, return 0
- if one argument is passed in, just return it
- I'm using JavaScript

This is what I tried but I really don't know what to do. Appreciate any help!

```
function multiplyArguments() {

    let product = 1;

   for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
   {
    product = product * arguments[i];
   }
  return product;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What problem are you experiencing with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiply all elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175063/multiply-all-elements-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Just add an `if` to handle the `0` args condition.

Note: you should prefer using [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) - you can see the differences [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object).

```js
function multiplyArguments(...args) {
  if(args.length === 0) return 0;

  let product = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    product = product * args[i];
  }
  
  return product;
}

console.log(multiplyArguments());
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4));
```

You can also use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const multiplyArguments = (...args) =>
  args.length
    ? args.reduce((prod, n) => prod * n)
    : 0;

console.log(multiplyArguments());
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function multiplyAllArgs(...args) {
  if(args.length === 0) return 0; 
  return args.reduce((arg, item) => (arg*item), 1);
}

console.log(multiplyAllArgs());
console.log(multiplyAllArgs(2));
console.log(multiplyAllArgs(2, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to multiply all arguments together inside an array and return the product
>
> - if no arguments are passed in, return 0
> - if one argument is passed in, just return it
> - I'm using JavaScript

These are somewhat strange requirements. The neutral element of multiplication is `1`, not `0`, so it would make much more sense to return `1` in case the collection is empty.

Typically, when you want to "reduce" elements of a collection into one value, the method to use for that is the aptly named [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce):

```js
const multiplyArguments = (...nums) => nums.reduce((acc, el) => acc * el, 1);

console.log(multiplyArguments());        //  1
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));       //  5
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));    // 10
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4)); // 40
```

As you can see, this is absolutely trivial if we want to return the neutral element for an empty collection, which is IMO the right way to go.

Modifying this to return `0` is simple, though: we can either conditionally pass a different neutral element, or conditionally bypass the `reduce` altogether.

Here we pass a different neutral element:

```js
const multiplyArguments = (...nums) => 
    nums.reduce(
        (acc, el) => acc * el,
        nums.length === 0 ? 0 : 1
    );

console.log(multiplyArguments());        //  0
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));       //  5
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));    // 10
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4)); // 40
```

We can be more clever and use the fact that `0` is *falsey* and all other numbers are *truthy*:

```js
const multiplyArguments = (...nums) => 
    nums.reduce(
        (acc, el) => acc * el,
        nums.length ? 1 : 0
    );

console.log(multiplyArguments());        //  0
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));       //  5
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));    // 10
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4)); // 40
```

We can be even more clever and use the fact that the numeric coercion of `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`:

```js
const multiplyArguments = (...nums) => 
    nums.reduce(
        (acc, el) => acc * el,
        +!!nums.length
    );

console.log(multiplyArguments());        //  0
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));       //  5
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));    // 10
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4)); // 40
```

Note that "being clever" sounds cool but is actually not a good idea! In particular, debugging code is *much harder* than writing it in the first place, which means that if you write code as clever as you can, you are by definition not smart enough to debug it!

Or, we just skip the `reduce` altogether:

```js
function multiplyArguments(...nums) {
    if (!nums.length) { return 0; }
    return nums.reduce(
        (acc, el) => acc * el,
        +!!nums.length
    );
}

console.log(multiplyArguments());        //  0
console.log(multiplyArguments(5));       //  5
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2));    // 10
console.log(multiplyArguments(5, 2, 4)); // 40
```

Note that `arguments` is deprecated and should not be used.