# What is wrong with this function that is supposed to find the multiplicative persistance of a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, algorithm

Multiplicative persistence is the number of times you have to multiply all the digits of a number till the number gets below 9.

```js
function persistence(num) {
  let count = 0
  let sum = 10
  let multiply = 10
  while (multiply > 9) {
    count += 1
    sum = num.toString().split("").map(Number)
    multiply = 1
    for (number in sum) {
      let answer = sum[number] * multiply
      multiply += answer
      num = multiply
    }
  }
  return count
}
console.log(persistence(39))
```

Example from CodeWars: 39 --> 3 (because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4 = 4 and 4 has only one digit)
So if num = 39 the function should return 3.

Comment: The problem is that you never declared a variable named `sum1`, so an error is thrown

Comment: You need to initialize `let sum1 = 1;` before the `for` loop.

Comment: That was a mistake. Its fixed

Comment: You seem to be doing summation as well? `multiply += answer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your function does not take into account that `num` may be less than 10:

```
let multiply = 10
while (multiply > 9) { // this condition will always true initially for any value of `num`
  count += 1 // ...which means this will always happen
  // other logic
}
```

(`num` may be less than 10 for all your use cases, but the function itself cannot know that; it should recognize and handle that scenario as well.)

Secondly, changing the value of the input parameter in a method whose *intent* is not to change that value, should preferably be avoided:

```
function persistence(num) {
  // other logic
  num = multiply
  // other logic
}
```

Thridly, there already exists a method that is ideal to use for doing exactly what you want to do to with `sum` for each time your `while` loop is run: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Your specific use case when using that method is covered at StackOverflow in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175063/multiply-all-elements-in-array#answer-19175132).

In the following implementation suggestion, I am using the variable `fiddledNum` throughout the method, rather than updating the input parameter `num` itself. `.reduce()` is used to multiply the digits in each iteration.

```
function persistence(num) {
  let fiddledNum = num;
  let count = 0
  let sum
  while (fiddledNum > 9) {
    count += 1
    sum = fiddledNum.toString().split("").map(Number)
    fiddledNum = sum.reduce((a, b) => a * b)
  }
  return count
}
```

To emphasize what `.reduce()` does, the argument names of `sum.reduce((a, b) => a * b)` may be made more descriptive; e.g. `sum.reduce((digitProduct, nextDigit) => digitProduct * nextDigit)`.